# Use of resistors in a circuit to relay status

Tags: resistors

I am currently reading up on electric vehicle service equipment and came across the proximity pilot and how the different resistors are used to communicate when the vehicle is ready to charge. I understand the concept that the potential difference reduces as more connections through resistors are added to the protective earth but can't get any supporting math as to how to calculate just how much the potential goes down with different resistive values.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand how this is achieved?

Comment: Using  A DAC resistor ladder and a spreadsheet "solver" with KVL is one way to find out

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=resistor+dac&client=firefox-b-m&sxsrf=ALiCzsb6kEPdzsOk-xrtw9EO1bBRUukyCw:1662373859086&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia-eqauf35AhWiJn0KHWKwAF0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1121&bih=712&dpr=2

Comment: You mention 'proximity pilot' in your text, but you seem to have reproduced the 'control pilot' table from [J1772 signalling circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772) in wikipedia. Checkout the schematic in that article. BTW, I found that artcile with a google search for 'proximity pilot'. The key components are R1, the 1k resistor in the EVSE, and R2 and other resistors to ground in the vehicle. Use the standard voltage divider formula.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the concepts used.@Neil_UK @Tony Stewart,

Comment: Good find Neil.

Comment: it's kind of similar to the venturi effect?

Comment: No but using resistor value coded status is also used by Apple and others to identify the power source

Answer (score 0):

In order to close this, using Neil's comment & [link](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SAE_J1772)
[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, the control pilot is what got my attention sorry I didn't confirm, I've read the notes in the links, the voltage divider concept is applied in the DAC and im not sure but it looks like the same concept in the pilot signals.

Comment: There is still something missing as I cannot reconcile the equation for Vout in voltage dividers into the DAC Vout.

Comment: I thought it was obvious  R2||2k4= CP-PE